# Unable to see image masked over the button

Tags: c#, wpf

I write the following code to show image over the button but when i run the project it is not displaying anything.

```
<Button x:Name="Employee">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Image Source="images/Employee.png" 
                           Width="50" 
                           Height="50"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
                <TextBlock>Add New Epmloyee</TextBlock>
            </Button>
```

Comment: I test your XAML code in my project and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The relative path is correct? The folder "images" must be located in the same folder where the Window's XAML is saved.

Ensure that the Build Action for file "Employee.png" is "Resource".

Comment: Suggestion: if you want to see the TextBlock you need to include it in the custom ControlTemplate you've created.

Comment: It shows me image before compilation in xaml preview window but didn't show at run time.  Should I post the whole code for the window ?

Comment: Never trust XAML designer! :-)))) Try to post the XAML code for the Window, please. Try to fix the URL of the image : <Image Source="/images/Employee.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>

Comment: Put a / before "images", so you force WPF to search for the image starting by the root of your project.

Comment: I did this but unable to see the image

Comment: Actually it's a grid inside a grid does it really matters ?

Comment: Try a Build --> Clean Solution and rebuild all the project. It's very strange, because the XAML code is correct.

Comment: Took a new solution add only the button with above code couldn't see the image.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your xaml code and it works fine. please make sure that you have images folder under your root directory and an image below it with name **employee.png**

Comment: It shows me image before compilation in xaml preview window but didn't show at run time. Should I post the whole code for the window ?

Comment: If the images are not showing up at runtime then you have to change Build Action property of your image to Resource

Comment: it shows me error for InitializeComponent(); at compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i nail the problem. The problem was that i create the folder by going directly to project folder through My Computer that's why it was not showing in Visual studio. Now I add the folder from VS and drag the images in it. And Woah! it works fine. Thanks to all of you.